# How to create unit test in Svelte using Vitest?

Tags: javascript, svelte, vitest

I have created a skeleton project using Sveltekit. I would like to create unit tests for three different files. One of the first files is the `index.js` under the `src/lib` folder:

```js
export function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

The other two files are a Svelte component. The home page is in the `src/routes/+page.svelte` file:

```html
<h1>Welcome to SvelteKit</h1>
<p>Visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev">kit.svelte.dev</a> to read the documentation</p>
```

The about page is in the `src/routes/about/+page.svelte` file:

```html
<script>
  export let foo = 'bar';
</script>

<input type="text" bind:value={foo} />
<div>Hi {foo}!</div>
```

In the About page, there is a property that can be changed by an input field. How to pass values to the component during the unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Setup environment

First, install the following libraries which are the prerequisites for testing Svelte components using Vitest:

```bash
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/svelte @testing-library/jest-dom jsdom
```

Next, create a `vitest.config.js` config with the following content:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  }
});
```

> Note: You can use different environments for testing, see the [environment](https://vitest.dev/config/#environment) documentation for more detail.

## Create unit tests

Once everything is configured, you can begin testing the components. The most straightforward is the `index.js` script. Create a `src/test` folder and write the first unit test for the script file:

```js
// index.test.js
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import { add } from '../lib/index.js';

describe('sum test', () => {
  it('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
    expect(add(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

Make sure the imported path is correct and the functions to test are added. For the home page test, the `jest-dom` library needs to be imported because of helper functions:

```js
// home.test.js
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';

import Home from '../routes/+page.svelte';

describe('Home route', () => {
  it('renders the div with default value', () => {
    const result = render(Home);
    
    const headerText = result.getByText('Welcome to SvelteKit');

    expect(headerText).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

You see that Svelte's testing library is rendering the component. The [render](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/api/#render) function has a lot of properties with which you find and get elements by ID, text, label, title, and so on.

Lastly, here is how to initialize the about component with the property:

```js
// about.test.js
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render } from '@testing-library/svelte';

import About from '../routes/about/+page.svelte';

describe('About route', () => {
  it('renders the div with default value', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(About);

    expect(getByText('Hi bar!')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('renders the div with property value', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(About, { foo: 'foo' });

    expect(getByText('Hi foo!')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

You can also use the `getByRole` and the `fireEvent` function to trigger the input field as well. After importing the `fireEvent` function add the following testcase at the end of the test suite:

```js
  it('renders the div with input field', async () => {
    const { getByText, getByRole } = render(About);

    const inputField = getByRole('textbox');
    await fireEvent.input(inputField, { target: { value: 'foobar' } });

    expect(getByText('Hi foobar!')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```